# Initialize a python class only once on webpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, web.py

I am using web.py to host a simple web service. The web service runs an analytics application in the backend (inside ClassA). During the initialization of web.py, I'd like to pre-load all data into the memory (i.e call  a = ClassA() only once when web server is started), and when the user sends a web request, the web server will just response with the pre-calculated result (i.e return a.do_something).

The code below seems to run **init**() of class 'add' everytime a HTTP POST request is received. This is a waste of time because the initialization stage takes pretty long. Is it possible to initialize ClassA only once?

```
import web
from aclass import ClassA

urls = (        
    '/add', 'add'
)

class add:
    def __init__(self):
        a = ClassA()

    def POST(self):
        return a.do_something()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
class add:
    a = ClassA()

    def POST(self):
        return add.a.do_something()
```

This will make it a class-bound parameter instead of a instance-bound one, i.e. only initializing it once.

Comment: Works, but wouldn't `self.a.do_something()` be better than `add.a.do_something()`? Either way, initialization occurs only once.

Comment: I can't judge which one is better, I simply wanted to emphasize the point that it is bound to the class, not to the instance. (One advantage I can see is that with `self` you can rename the class without breaking the function.)